# ember.js triggering an action based on conditional

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, action

I have an action that I want to trigger in my component hbs file if a conditional returns true. For example, If my component.js file looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  toggleMe: false,
  actions: {
    changeValue() {
      return this.toggleProperty('toggleMe');
    }
  }
});
```

I want to call that changeValue action in my hbs file. This is the approach that I have tried in my component.hbs file:

```
{{#if model.property}}
    {{action changeValue}}
{{/if}}
```

I'm getting an error

```
"Assertion Failed: Action passed is null or undefined"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call an action in a template file.
There are computed properties for this.
Here is an example:

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  toggleMe: false,
  toggleComputedProperty: computed('toggleMe', function() {^
      return this.toggleProperty('toggleMe');
    }
  }
});
```

Now you have the toggleComputedProperty availible to use in your template or in your logic.

As a rule of thumb: Never try to do logic/state changing in your template file. Use computed properties or other features for this.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a misspelled syntax in the component hbs. It should start with `{{`.

Second, your requirement can be done by using a `Ember observer`.

Created a [live ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c030d504116528d60e4cbea051cd0258?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) for your understanding.

Modify your component js file as,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  toggleMe: false,
  handleProperty : function()
  {
        this.send("changeValue");
  }.observes('modeldata.property').on('didInsertElement'),
  actions: {
    changeValue() {
      //console.log(this.get("toggleMe"));
      this.toggleProperty('toggleMe');
      //console.log(this.get("toggleMe"));
    }
  }
});
```

Also you may want to read about [Ember computed properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/object-model/computed-properties/) and [Ember observers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/observers/).

Comment: Interesting. I'll look more into observables. Using a computed property was what ended up working. @shimu's solution below. I can see how observables could solve the problem too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the misspelled syntax during your action call. You must use double quotes for your action name when invoking them.

```
{#if model.property}}
  {{action "changeValue"}}
{{/if}}
```

I have also added an [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4f480db3622f6639b91dad833f113a55?openFiles=templates.components.test-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.test-component.hbs) for your reference.

Comment: I was trying to call the action without the use of a button/submit form. Otherwise your solution would work. @shimu's solution is what I was looking for.